# UI 404 - Vault Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

I'm testing out Vault in Kubernetes and am installing via the Helm chart. I've created an overrides file,  it's an amalgamation of a few different pages from the official docs.

The pods seem to come up OK and into Ready status and I can unseal vault manually using 3 of the keys generated. I'm having issues getting 404 when browsing the UI though, the UI is presented externally on a Load Balancer in AKS. Here's my config:

```
global:
  enabled: true
  tlsDisable: false

injector:
  enabled: false

server:

  readinessProbe:
    enabled: true
    path: "/v1/sys/health?standbyok=true&sealedcode=204&uninitcode=204"
  # livenessProbe:
  #   enabled: true
  #   path: "/v1/sys/health?standbyok=true"
  #   initialDelaySeconds: 60

  extraEnvironmentVars:
    VAULT_CACERT: /vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.ca

  extraVolumes:
    - type: secret
      name: vault-server-tls # Matches the ${SECRET_NAME} from above

  standalone:
    enabled: true
    config: |
      listener "tcp" {
        address = "[::]:8200"
        cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
        tls_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.crt"
        tls_key_file  = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.key"
        tls_client_ca_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.ca"
      }

      storage "file" {
        path = "/vault/data"
      }

# Vault UI
ui:
  enabled: true
  serviceType: "LoadBalancer"
  serviceNodePort: null
  externalPort: 443

  # For Added Security, edit the below
  #  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
          #    5.69.25.6/32
```

I'm still trying to get to grips with Vault. My liveness probe is commented out because it was permanently failing and causing the pod to be re-scheduled, even though checking the vault service status it appeared to be healthy and awaiting an unseal. That's a side issue though compared to the UI, just mentioning in case the failing liveness is related.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I don't think the documentation around deploying in Kubernetes from Helm is really that clear but I was basically missing a `ui = true` flag from the HCL config stanza. It's to be noted that this is in addition to the value passed to the helm chart:

```
# Vault UI
ui:
  enabled: true
  serviceType: "LoadBalancer"
  serviceNodePort: null
  externalPort: 443
```

Which I had mistakenly assumed was enough to enable the UI.

Here's the config now, with working UI:

```
global:
  enabled: true
  tlsDisable: false

injector:
  enabled: false

server:

  readinessProbe:
    enabled: true
    path: "/v1/sys/health?standbyok=true&sealedcode=204&uninitcode=204"

  extraEnvironmentVars:
    VAULT_CACERT: /vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.ca

  extraVolumes:
    - type: secret
      name: vault-server-tls # Matches the ${SECRET_NAME} from above

  standalone:
    enabled: true
    config: |
      ui = true
      listener "tcp" {
        address = "[::]:8200"
        cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
        tls_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.crt"
        tls_key_file  = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.key"
        tls_client_ca_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.ca"
      }

      storage "file" {
        path = "/vault/data"
      }

# Vault UI
ui:
  enabled: true
  serviceType: "LoadBalancer"
  serviceNodePort: null
  externalPort: 443
```